# Is the config of Session() valid for all Session() object?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I use the config args of Session() to prevent the tensorflow process from occupying all the GPU memory. My test code is as followings:

```
import os
import math
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = '0'
config = tf.ConfigProto()  
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True


input_length = 10
output_length = 10
n_epochs = 10000
n_batches = 10

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, input_length], name="x_in")
W = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([input_length, output_length],
                                  -1.0 / math.sqrt(input_length),
                                  1.0 / math.sqrt(input_length)), name="w")
Out = tf.matmul(X, W, name="out")


sess1 = tf.Session(config=config)
sess2 = tf.Session()

sess2.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
for epoch_i in range(n_epochs):
    print("epoch {}.".format(epoch_i))
    for batch in range(n_batches):
        batch = np.random.rand(50, input_length)
        out = sess2.run([Out], feed_dict={X: batch})

sess1.close()
sess2.close()
```

I use `sess2` to run the graph and the GPU occupation is 241MB.
My question is that I just use `config=config` to initialize the `sess1`, why it still work for `sess2`? If I close `sess1` before declaring `sess2`:

```
sess1 = tf.Session(config=config)
sess1.close()
sess2 = tf.Session()

sess2.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
for epoch_i in range(n_epochs):
    print("epoch {}.".format(epoch_i))
    for batch in range(n_batches):
        batch = np.random.rand(50, input_length)
        out = sess2.run([Out], feed_dict={X: batch})

sess2.close()
```

The GPU occupation is still 241 MB instead of all the GPU. Could anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can try below things to release GPU memory allocated after session close.

1. Put both your session code in different subprocess. So, when the subprocess is finished after calling sess.close() it will release the resources used by it.
2. Use tf.reset_default_graph() after sess.close()
3. Use Pool to create different single process for different session
4. Use CUDA and try cuda.close

Check out [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/19731) link for more info.

Comment: My question isn't about how to release the GPU memory. My point is that I use `config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True` and `sess1 = tf.Session(config=config)` to   initialize the `sess1`. Then I use another session `sess2` to run the graph. The occupation of GPU is just 241 MB. In my opinion, the process should occupy all the GPU memory because I haven't told `sess2` not to occupy all the GPU source.

Comment: Until you have set the config to  gpu_options.allow_growth = true, you will not be able to use all the GPU memory